# Remove rows which have less than string into a specific column

Tags: r

How is it possible to remove rows which contain in a specific column less than 4 strings? Strings are separated by single space

Example input

```
dd <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                 text = c("remove this", "also remove this", "you can keep it however")
```

Example of expected output:

```
data.frame(id = 3,
           text = c("you can keep it however")
```

Comment: Expected output, id should be just 3, right?

Comment: @zx8754 right. I updated it. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use *tidyverse* packages you could use:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dd %>% filter(str_count(text, " ") >= 3)
```

Here we assume that "less than 4 strings" means less than 3 spaces. By counting characters, you can have a much more efficient solution than actually going though the work of splitting the string up and allocating the memory for the separate pieces when you don't really need them.

Comment: I like the reverse logic, count spaces instead of words.

Answer (score 2):

Using base R:

```
df
  id                    text
1  1             remove this
2  2        also remove this
3  3 you can keep it however
df$str_count <- sapply(strsplit(df$text, split = ' '), length)
df$text <- df$text[which(df$str_count>4)]
df$str_count <- NULL
df
  id                    text
1  1 you can keep it however
2  2 you can keep it however
3  3 you can keep it however
```

If you just need the particular row:

```
df[which(sapply(strsplit(df$text, split = ' '), length)>4), ]
  id                    text
3  3 you can keep it however
```

Answer (score 2):

Split on space, then check the length:

```
dd[ lengths(strsplit(dd$text, " ")) > 4, ]
#   id                    text
# 3  3 you can keep it however
```